# Help decoding a regular expression for use with Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

**Update**

I missed this in my original explanation.  I set this up yesterday, and it ran over night.  No data populated in my profile overnight.  So, either my regex is wrong, or Google cannot see internal traffic IPs.

It seems that everyone has their own variation on the syntax for regular expressions.

I'm trying to include only internal traffic on one of my profiles in Google Analytics

[image]

Can someone verify for me what they expect that regular expression to match?  In CIDER notation?

Comment: Oops, you all caught an important issue.  the 2nd and 3rd octet are mutually inclusive.  90.10 only or 60.10 only

Comment: `^10\.(90\.10|60\.9)\.[0-9].[0-9]?[0-9]?$` does this seem more correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what CIDER notation is, but that regex matches a string that

- starts with `10.`
- followed by `90.` or `60.`
- followed by `10` or `9`
- followed by zero or more dots.

You probably want `^10\.[96]0\.(10|9)\..*$`

Since the last bit (`.*`) is a bit too vague (unless you know that there will only ever be valid IP addresses in the live data), you might want to change that to `\d+` or (if you want to restrict to a valid range from 0 to 255) `25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d?\d`

Comment: followed by 0 or more dots, not anything.

Comment: according to Google Documentation \d is not a valid expression.  Don't say google's own documentation is not complete?!

Comment: final result, `^10\.(90\.10|60\.9)\.[0-9]{1,3}$`, I tested this using. http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about CIDR notation, but that will match any of 10.90.9.*, 10.90.10.*, 10.60.9.* or 10.60.10.*

Answer (score 0):

instead of the last asterisk, place `\d+`. The way you wrote it, in the end you've got to have 0 or more dots for the expression to validate.